# After having updated Fedora, v4l2loopback does not work anymore

Tags: fedora, v4l2loopback

After having upgraded from Fedora 33 to Fedora 34, it seems that v4l2loopback does not work anymore. I did install v4l2loopback-dkms from

https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/sentry/v4l2loopback/

and rebooted, but the problem persists.

Now, I have the following:

```
$ v4l2-ctl --all
Driver Info:
    Driver name      : v4l2 loopback
    Card type        : OBS Virtual Camera
    Bus info         : platform:v4l2loopback-000
    Driver version   : 5.11.16
    Capabilities     : 0x85208002
        Video Output
        Video Memory-to-Memory
        Read/Write
        Streaming
        Extended Pix Format
        Device Capabilities
    Device Caps      : 0x05208002
        Video Output
        Video Memory-to-Memory
        Read/Write
        Streaming
        Extended Pix Format
Priority: 0
Video output: 0 (loopback in)
Format Video Output:
    Width/Height      : 0/0
    Pixel Format      : 'BGR4' (32-bit BGRA/X 8-8-8-8)
    Field             : None
    Bytes per Line    : 0
    Size Image        : 0
    Colorspace        : sRGB
    Transfer Function : Default (maps to sRGB)
    YCbCr/HSV Encoding: Default (maps to ITU-R 601)
    Quantization      : Default (maps to Full Range)
    Flags             : 
Streaming Parameters Video Capture:
    Frames per second: 30.000 (30/1)
    Read buffers     : 2
Streaming Parameters Video Output:
    Frames per second: 30.000 (30/1)
    Write buffers    : 2

User Controls

                    keep_format 0x0098f900 (bool)   : default=0 value=0
              sustain_framerate 0x0098f901 (bool)   : default=0 value=0
                        timeout 0x0098f902 (int)    : min=0 max=100000 step=1 default=0 value=0
               timeout_image_io 0x0098f903 (bool)   : default=0 value=0
$
```

However, no video from my camera is shown on OBS-Studio.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's hardly relevant these days, but still - you didn't specify, what's your video source you are piping to the v4l2loopback device, so we can only guess. Today I'm running the module (installed from rpmfusion) in Fedora 37 without any problems.